# PAD Rank up grind locations

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

So I'm rank 104, and I'm finding it very difficult to rank up. Weekend Dungeon seems to yield out nice exp, but is there another dungeon similar to Tower of Giant's where it's the most cost efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At that level, the best place to grind is Oceans of Heaven last floor.  You get about 6k XP but also 30-40k coins.  Just remember to pack an armour breaker or deal massive damage to take out Neptune.  This is also good for farming + eggs on the weekend.  (as well as the occasional Mystic Mask and High Metal Dragon drops)

Answer (score 0):

I'm rank 145, and I find that doing the `Technical dungeons` give decent exp. In the `Skydragon Rush`, the one that costs 25 stamina gives ALOT of exp, but it takes a bit to get through it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also go for the dungeons unlocked after Tomb of the Saint - Deep (Hyperion Lava Flow, Oceanus Falls, Kronos Forest, in particular, because it's usually more than 500 XP/Stamina at the 3rd level of each one of those). Of course, Starlight Sanctuary (if you can do it), at its 4th and 5th levels, you can earn lots of XP and a decent amount of gold.